# asp.net blocking IP range

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config

I want to do a IP range block on a asp.net mvc website, and I have this in my web.config:

```
  <system.webServer>
<security>
  <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false">
    <add ipAddress="1.1.1.1" subnetMask="255.255.0.0" />
    <add ipAddress="2.2.2.2" subnetMask="255.255.0.0" />
  </ipSecurity>
</security>


<handlers>
  ...
</handlers>
```

But when i try to run the page I get this

[image: IIS Error]

How should i do the ip range block?

Comment: Have you got that module installed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23204788/trying-to-secure-all-aspx-files-in-a-folder-secure-by-ip-address

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need the [IP Security](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/ipsecurity) module installed on your local IIS (and your server when you go live). The error has a problem with the line:

```
<ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false">
```

Which is correct, although currently with `allowUnlisted` set to `false`, you're currently only allowing the IPs specified in your rule, and looks like you want the opposite, so set that to `true`.

Comment: i explained myself wrong, i want to only allow 2 ranges of ips and block the rest.

Comment: Ah then just ignore the latter part of my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/azure/jj154098.aspx):

> First, create a command file that runs when your role starts which
> unlocks the ipSecurity section of the ApplicationHost.config file.
> Create a new folder at the root level of your web role called startup
> and, within this folder, create a batch file called startup.cmd. Set
> the properties of this file to Copy Always to ensure that it will be
> deployed.
>
> Add the following code to the startup.cmd file:
>
> ```
> %windir%\system32\inetsrv\AppCmd.exe unlock config -section:system.webServer/security/ipSecurity
> ```
>
> Next, open the ServiceDefinition.csdef file in your web role project
> and add the following element:
>
> ```
> <Startup>
>    <Task commandLine=”startup\startup.cmd” executionContext=”elevated” />
> </Startup>
> ```
>
> This causes the startup.cmd batch file to be run every time the web
> role is initialized, ensuring that the required ipSecurity section is
> unlocked.

In case if you didn't load module.

Then if you want black list you should change `<ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false">` to `<ipSecurity allowUnlisted="true">`

Really good article of how it works [could be found here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150531060045/http://www.stokia.com/support/misc/web-config-ip-address-restriction.aspx).