# Is it possible to only allow selected IP range to access a website in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, http, ip

I'm trying to lay my hands on MVC currently but I'm a rookie for the moment. I'm tasked to build an intranet web application on ASP.Net MVC5 but I hesitate to do so because it will restrict users in many ways, such as they ought to be in queue sitting on companies PCs and accomplish the required tasks that they are obliged for.

I have read and found out that there is an available option through Web.config file but that is applied if the web application is to be hosted in IIS whereas the web application should be hosted from another server online. [Stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337842/is-it-possible-to-configure-a-location-in-web-config-to-only-allow-local-connect)

To sum up, I want to enable the website I'm going to create to only be accessible from any device connected to the wireless/cable network of our company whether it is from a PC or from a smartphone/tablet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Restrict access to a specific controller by IP address in ASP.NET MVC Beta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473687/restrict-access-to-a-specific-controller-by-ip-address-in-asp-net-mvc-beta)

Comment: Host the web site inside your company's intranet only. That should be protected from outside access by firewalls.