# Using the Plesk Windows Scheduler to call an ASP

Tags: asp.net, scheduled-tasks, plesk

I want to run a schedule to call an asp page.

I add an asp page to project and add function to load page.

I use [this](http://www.net24.co.nz/kb/article/AA-00213/13/Shared-Hosting/ASP-ASP.NET/Using-the-Plesk-Windows-Scheduler-to-call-an-ASP-or-.NET-page.html) tutorial for add scheduler in plesk, and add vb script to it.

When i go to www.mysite.com/schedule.aspx page , it run function. But when i run Scheduled Tasks in plesk, don't run function.

```
Call RunIt()
Sub RunIt()

Dim RequestObj
Dim URL
Set RequestObj = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")

'Request URL...
URL = "my site address/schedule.aspx"

'Open request and pass the URL
RequestObj.open "POST", URL , false

'Send Request
RequestObj.Send

'cleanup
Set RequestObj = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Plesk 12.5 has task type to call web page, what is the Plesk version you are using?

Comment: I use 12.5.30 version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is possible to create task for every 5 minute by "cron style" = "0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * *"

You can create domain level task with type "Fetch a URL" where you can request your page:

[image: ![scheduled-task-plesk-12.5-3-fetch-url-cron-style-every-five-minutes.png]

Comment: Thanks, I use `Fetch a URL` and set run `Hourly (at 05 min)` , when i use `Run Now` it is ok, and run function on page. But don't run automatic every 5 min :(

Comment: There is possible to create task for every 5 minute by "cron style" = "0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * *"

Comment: how we can **secure** the page that fetched by URL?

Comment: @PurTahan via web.config https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337842/is-it-possible-to-configure-a-location-in-web-config-to-only-allow-local-connect